# Sawtooth Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am new to blockchain and want to do some specific task using Javascript Sdk of sawtooth in Node Js but unable to run it successfully. Please find the code below, am getting this error as below

I am new to this sawtooth code.Could anyone guide me how to use for a custom application like barcode validation ?

//**Errror**

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 30,
    "message": "The submitted BatchList was rejected by the validator. It was poorly formed, or has an invalid signature.",
    "title": "Submitted Batches Invalid"
  }
}
```

//**Code**

```
const {createContext, CryptoFactory} = require('sawtooth-sdk/signing')

const context = createContext('secp256k1')
const privateKey = context.newRandomPrivateKey();

const signer = new CryptoFactory(context).newSigner(privateKey)
const cbor = require('cbor')

const payload = {
    Verb: 'set',
    Name: 'foo',
    Value: 42
}

const payloadBytes = cbor.encode(payload)
const {createHash} = require('crypto')
const {protobuf} = require('sawtooth-sdk')
const transactionHeaderBytes = protobuf.TransactionHeader.encode({
    familyName: 'intkey',
    familyVersion: '1.0',
    inputs: [createHash('sha512').update("intkey").digest('hex')],
    outputs: [createHash('sha512').update("intkey").digest('hex')],
    signerPublicKey: signer.getPublicKey().asHex(),
    // In this example, we're signing the batch with the same private key,
    // but the batch can be signed by another party, in which case, the
    // public key will need to be associated with that key.
    batcherPublicKey: signer.getPublicKey().asHex(),
    // In this example, there are no dependencies.  This list should include
    // an previous transaction header signatures that must be applied for
    // this transaction to successfully commit.
    // For example,
    // dependencies: ['540a6803971d1880ec73a96cb97815a95d374cbad5d865925e5aa0432fcf1931539afe10310c122c5eaae15df61236079abbf4f258889359c4d175516934484a'],
    dependencies: [],
    payloadSha512: createHash('sha512').update(payloadBytes).digest('hex')
}).finish()
const signature = signer.sign(transactionHeaderBytes);

const transaction = protobuf.Transaction.create({
    header: transactionHeaderBytes,
    headerSignature: signature,
    payload: payloadBytes
})

const transactions = [transaction]

const batchHeaderBytes = protobuf.BatchHeader.encode({
    signerPublicKey: signer.getPublicKey().asHex(),
    transactionIds: transactions.map((txn) => txn.headerSignature),
}).finish()
const batch = protobuf.Batch.create({
    header: batchHeaderBytes,
    headerSignature: signature,
    transactions: transactions
});
const batchListBytes = protobuf.BatchList.encode({
    batches: [batch]
}).finish()

const request = require('request')

request.post({
    url: 'http://192.168.99.100:8008/batches',
    body: batchListBytes,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}
}, (err, response) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    console.log(response.body)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `intkey-client` to the access `intkey` processor, here's a github repo for that:

https://github.com/thegreatsunra/intkey-client-js

Answer (score 0):

Most likey you are not putting the transaction into a batch or the batch in a batchlist for posting to the REST API.  This is required, even for a single transaction.

Here's a simple, standalone demo Sawtooth application (Simple Wallet) written in JavaScript and other languages that can server as an example:
https://github.com/askmish/sawtooth-simplewallet

Edit: I looked at it again.  You should follow the int key example in the link above.  I noticed, for example, that you do not set the "nonce", which is a one time number (use a random number).  Compare your code with:

https://github.com/askmish/sawtooth-simplewallet/blob/master/jsclient/routes/SimpleWalletClient.js
or
https://github.com/thegreatsunra/intkey-client-js/blob/develop/sawtooth-client.js

Answer (score 0):

Try this Out Please make necessary Changes.

```
const transactionHeaderBytes = protobuf.TransactionHeader.encode({
    familyName: FAMILY_NAME,
    familyVersion: '1.0',
    inputs: [createHash('sha512').update(FAMILY_NAME).digest('hex').toLowerCase().slice(0, 6)],
    outputs: [createHash('sha512').update(FAMILY_NAME).digest('hex').toLowerCase().slice(0, 6)],
    signerPublicKey: signer.getPublicKey().asHex(),
    batcherPublicKey: signer.getPublicKey().asHex(),
    dependencies: [],
    payloadSha512: createHash('sha512').update(payloadBytes).digest('hex')
}).finish()

const signature = signer.sign(transactionHeaderBytes)

const transaction = protobuf.Transaction.create({
    header: transactionHeaderBytes,
    headerSignature: signature,
    payload: payloadBytes
})


const transactions = [transaction]

const batchHeaderBytes = protobuf.BatchHeader.encode({
    signerPublicKey: signer.getPublicKey().asHex(),
    transactionIds: transactions.map((txn) => txn.headerSignature),
}).finish()

const signature1 = signer.sign(batchHeaderBytes)

const batch = protobuf.Batch.create({
    header: batchHeaderBytes,
    headerSignature: signature1,
    transactions: transactions
})


const batchListBytes = protobuf.BatchList.encode({
    batches: [batch]
}).finish();
```